# Совместимость программы на Delphi с Vista

Tags: vista, delphi

Здравствуйте.
Программа была написана в Embarcadero RAD Studio Delphi 2010, ОС Windows 7 32-бит... При запуске программы на Vista, вылезают ошибки разного рода... Что делать?...

К примеру в FormCreate...

```
  dir:='c:/Dir';
  fileName:='c:/Dir/files.txt';

  if (DirectoryExists(dir)) then {проверяем наличие директории}
  begin
   if (FileExists(fileName)) then  {проверяем наличие файла}
    begin
    AssignFile(usersfile, fileName);
    Reset(usersfile);
    while not Eof(usersfile) do
    begin
      i:=i+1;
      ReadLn(usersfile, temp[i]);{читаем из файла пользователя}
    end;
    CloseFile(usersfile);
   end;
  end else
   begin
   ForceDirectories(dir);
   AssignFile(usersfile, fileName);
   ReWrite(usersfile);
   CloseFile(usersfile);
   end;
```

при нажатие на кнопку

```
      AssignFile(usersfile, fileName);
      Append(usersfile);
      WriteLn(usersfile, edit1.text);  // значения из текстовых полей
      WriteLn(usersfile, edit2.text);
      WriteLn(usersfile, edit3.text);
      WriteLn(usersfile, edit4.Text);
      CloseFile(usersfile);
```

возникает ошибка invalid specification files %s...

Также возникает ошибка при подключение к серверу...

Спасибо.

Comment: Можно будет уточнить что за ошибка и к какому серверу вы пытаетесь подключиться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь получить доступ к файлам, к которым имеет доступ только админ. В Vista и Seven для этого нужно повысить привилегии (копайте в сторону UAC). Так делают все инсталляторы.

Если для вас критично использовать именно эти пути, то повышайте привилегии у приложения (опять же UAC + Delphi + Google), если нет - создавайте файлы в папке TEMP, папке с Документами, другими словами там, где у вас есть доступ.

Answer (score 0):

Может попробовать использовать более привычный для windows формат пути?

```
dir:='c:\Dir';
fileName:='c:\Dir\files.txt';
```

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я помню, в win7 нужно давать полные права использования (свойства - безопасность - изменить - %username% - полный доступ). Была такая же проблема, решилась именно таким образом.